# convert string with UTC offset to spark timestamp offset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I am trying to convert string coming from s3/csv files to aurora mysql using sparksql (spark cluster 3.0) using Glue

Existing string value from csv: 20231021134021+0100
Expected timestamp: 2023-10-21 14:40:21 (added offset hour to time)

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame


# Use Spark SQL to parse the date-time string and add the time zone offset
spark_sql = glueContext.sql("""
    SELECT
           DATE_ADD(
               to_timestamp(SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 1, 14), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),
               INTERVAL CAST(SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 15, 2) AS INT) HOURS
               + CAST(SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 17, 2) AS INT) MINUTES
           ) AS 
    FROM my_data
""")

result_df = spark.sql(spark_sql)

result_dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(result_df, glueContext, "result_dyf")
```

I am getting a parsing error, is cast not supported with INTERVAL?
and if I'm just using till timestamp like below

```
select to_timestamp(SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 1, 14), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') from my_data
```

or
select to_timestamp(SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 1, 14), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE from my_data
both works well but not when i use cast from extracting offset

any better ways to handle on how to also include offset value inside timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark SQL, the INTERVAL keyword generally expects a constant
or a column value that has an appropriate interval type.
So the CAST as INT before using it with INTERVAL doesn't work directly in this case.

What you need to do is:

- Parse the date-time string into a timestamp.
- Add the UTC offset to the parsed timestamp.

I would change the sql to

```
# SQL query to transform the data
spark_sql = glueContext.sql("""
    SELECT
        from_utc_timestamp(
            to_timestamp(SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 1, 14), 
         'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),
            CONCAT('GMT', SUBSTRING(your_datetime_column, 15, 5))
        ) AS timestamp_with_offset
    FROM my_data
""")
```

`to_timestamp()` function converts the date-time part of the string into a timestamp.

`from_utc_timestamp()` function applies the time zone offset to the timestamp.It expects the time zone in the format 'GMT+0100', which is created using string manipulation. So `from_utc_timestamp` function takes the timestamp as being in UTC and converts it to the local time of the timezone specified.

This should correctly add the offset to the time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated `x` [pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for zone offset, so parsing your string  value is as simple as:

```scala
spark.sql("""select to_timestamp('20231021134021+0100', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssxx') as ts""").show
+-------------------+
|                 ts|
+-------------------+
|2023-10-21 14:40:21|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: this is great, i am new to spark sql
it did minus one hour though it had +0100 and minus 2 hours when i mentioned +0200, any idea what could be the reasons?
as a workaround, for now, i have used make_interval but would definitely change to your solution once this one hour gets sorted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you could edit your question and provide a few more examples of input and expected output to make it more clear.

Comment: what am trying to say is if am using to_timstamp for value having offset as +0100, the my converted timestamp is getting -1 hour instead of +1 hour and same case if am giving +0200, its doing -2 hours, so wierd.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your problem then.